# Case no where para filtro de consultas

Tags: sql, sql-server, datatable

Eu tenho este `select` abaixo, porém quando data for `true`, ele precisa trazer todos os registros onde o campo `OrdemServicos.DataConclusao` é diferente de null, e quando for `false` precisa trazer todos onde o `OrdemServicos.DataConclusao`é igual a null, e quando o @data for null, precisa trazer os dois, como resolver, ele não entende o Is not null, estou colocando em um dataset, para relatórios.

```
    SELECT        OrdemServicos.DataConclusao, OrdemServicos.ValorTotal, OrdemServicos.ClienteId, OrdemServicos.OrcamentoId, Marca.Descricao AS marca, Modelo.Descricao AS modelo, Clientes.Nome, Empresas.RazaoSocial, Veiculos.Placa, Veiculos.Cor
FROM            OrdemServicos INNER JOIN
                         Empresas ON Empresas.Id = OrdemServicos.EmpresaId INNER JOIN
                         Clientes ON Clientes.Id = OrdemServicos.ClienteId INNER JOIN
                         Veiculos ON Veiculos.Id = OrdemServicos.VeiculoId INNER JOIN
                         Modelo ON Modelo.Id = Veiculos.ModeloId INNER JOIN
                         Marca ON Marca.Id = Veiculos.MarcaId
where (Clientes.id = @idcliente or @idcliente is null)
and (Empresas.id = @idempresa or @idempresa is null)
and (Veiculos.id = @idveiculo or @idveiculo is null)
and (CASE WHEN @data = 'true' THEN OrdemServicos.DataConclusao IS NOT NULL 
 WHEN @data = 'false' THEN ordemservicos.dataconclusao is null)
```

Comment: and ( (@data = 'true' and OrdemServicos.DataConclusao IS NOT NULL) or (data = 'false' and ordemservicos.dataconclusao is null))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O problema é que o SQL não tem suporte para condicionais de **IS NULL** ou **NOT NULL** referenciado de um case, o máximo que ele faz é o seguinte:

```
SELECT *
FROM atendimento atd
WHERE atd.cd_paciente >
(case when 1 = 1 then 1
 ELSE 100
 END)
```

Há várias outras formas de resolver seu problema, muito provavelmente isso é uma procedure, no caso eu utilizaria **IFS**, por exemplo:

```
IF @data = 'true' THEN 

   SELECT
   INTO tabela_final
   ...
   WHERE   OrdemServicos.DataConclusao IS NOT NULL

 ELSIF @data = 'false'

   SELECT
   INTO tabela_final
   ...
   WHERE   OrdemServicos.DataConclusao IS NOT NULL 

 ELSE

   SELECT
   INTO tabela_final
   ...
 END IF;

 --Consultando a tabela final
 SELECT * FROM tabela_final;
```

É necessário criar uma rotina de limpeza dessa tabela, ou dropa-la e cria-la toda vez que executasse a procedure:

```
--EXCLUINDO TABELA
DROP TABLE tabela_final;

    IF @data = 'true' THEN 

   SELECT
   INTO tabela_final
   ...
   WHERE   OrdemServicos.DataConclusao IS NOT NULL

 ELSIF @data = 'false'

   SELECT
   INTO tabela_final
   ...
   WHERE   OrdemServicos.DataConclusao IS NOT NULL 

 ELSE

   SELECT
   INTO tabela_final
   ...
 END IF;

 --Consultando a tabela final
 SELECT * FROM tabela_final;
```

No exemplo acima é bom adicionar uma condicional para verificar se a tabela existe, para evitar erros desnecessários. Você poderá utilizar o **IF_EXIST** caso utilize o SQL SERVER.

Com esse método é possível resolver a maioria dos casos dos problemas desse tipo.

Comment: Estou tentando fazer para gerar um relatório, `reportivew`, porém ele não reconhece o `if`, e informa que a `@data` precisa ser declarada.

Comment: Por que você não cria uma trigger, um job, ou uma rotina manual que cria essa tabela final e no reporte você apenas utilize o comando select?  SELECT * FROM tabela_final WHERE campo_condicional = CASE WHEN 1, 2, 3, etc... ; com uma condicional de 1,2,3 dependendo do case da variável @data, como fosse no meu primeiro exemplo?

Comment: Claro que nessa rotina será necessário criar uma coluna de verificação. Se for possível criar algo do tipo, eu posso criar um exemplo para você.

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda, consegui um norte.